# How to script Gnome window manager?

Tags: gnome, scripts

I would like to write some scripts for the window manager in Gnome. I would like to query all windows, monitors and workspaces. Then I would like to move the windows using my custom algorithm.

Are there any APIs for this task?

Comment: Wouldn't [`wmctrl`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/wmctrl.1.html) work for you?